# Helm template pass array of string value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

how do you pass array of string to helm template? and it should be like comma separated

so i want to set for the template via `--set`

i already trying this in my template

```
command: {{ .Values.web.job.commands }}
```

i set using this

```
--set web.job.commands={sleep 3}
```

but the result

```
command: [sleep 3]
```

i want to have like the usual command style

```
command: ["sleep","3"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the problem here `command: {{ .Values.web.job.commands }}` ,In this usage, the data structure represented by `{{ .Values.web.job.commands }}` will be output here in a way similar to `toString`, so you get unexpected results [sleep 3]

If you want to get `command: ["sleep","3"]`, you may need to

values.yaml

```yaml
web:
  job:
    commands: '["wake", "2"]'
```

templates/xxx.tpl

```yaml
...
 command: {{ tpl .Values.web.job.commands . }}
...
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
...
  command: ["wake", "2"]
...
```

cmd:

```bash
helm template --debug test . --set web.job.commands='[\"sleep\"\, \"3\"]'
```

output

```yaml
...
  command: ["sleep", "3"]
...
```

---

However, the better usage in this scenario is as follows

values.yaml

```yaml
web:
  job:
    commands:
      - "wake"
      - "2"
```

templates/xxx.tpl

```yaml
...
  command:
    {{ toYaml .Values.web.job.commands | nindent x }}
...
```

(Modify `x` according to the actual indentation)

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
...
  command:
    - wake
    - "2"
...
```

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test . --set web.job.commands={"sleep"\,"3"}
```

output

```yaml
...
  command:
    - sleep
    - 3
...
```